# $m<n<\omega\Rightarrow |n\setminus\{m\}|<n$ in weaker theories

Tags: logic, set-theory

My question is about the following proposition:
\begin{equation}
A\subseteq B\land |B|=|A|<\omega\Rightarrow A=B.
\end{equation}
It seems to me that some form of induction is needed to prove this fact. The question is: if I not assume the foundation axiom $Fnd$, it is possible to find a model of $T:=ZF\setminus\{Fnd\}$ such that the previous proposition does not holds anymore?

I think that the key-point is: what I really need in order to prove that
$$
m<n<\omega\Rightarrow |n\setminus\{m\}|<n?
$$
Is it possible to find a non-standard model $(M,\in^M)$ of $T$, with a non-standard natural number $k\in M$ such that

$|k\setminus\{n\}|^M=|k|^M$ for some $n\in^M k$?

(In that case I might consider $k$ as $B$ and $k\setminus\{n\}$ as $A$ for any $n\in^M k$)

If $M$ preserves the cardinality (that is if $|a|^M=|a|$ for all $a\in M$) then I think that the answer is affermative, because a non-standard number is necessarily infinite.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the axiom of foundation, since you only need to do induction over $\omega$; and $\omega$ is well-founded by definition; even in the absence of the axiom of foundation.

Comment: Ok, sorry you're obviously right: $\omega$ is an inductive set by definition and then well-founded. Should I infer that "$\forall n\in\omega\forall m\in n(n\setminus\{m\}\text{ is not in bijection with }n)$" holds in every model of, for example, $\{\text{Extensionality, There exists an inductive set}\}$?

Comment: Anyway, I think that the question is misleading, because I think that the induction can be avoided simply by proving that for all $A$, $|A|=n<\omega\land a\in A\Rightarrow |A\setminus\{a\}|<n$. It seems to me that this does not require induction and it is enough to conclude the main sentence.